# Logstash not working properly when multiple data is being written to file simultaneously

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am trying to insert logs from file to clickhouse db. I have done with the configuration and testing by inserting few lines into the file manually. But when i try to do the same on live log file which is continously being written, logstash is not able work properly with it. It working fine when I do "echo 'some log here' >> /tmp/testing.log" and the log with correct pattern in "grok" matches and get stored in redis and clickhouse db. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, need guidance on this as I have already utilized more time in debugging the same.

**Log**

```
{"level":"info","msg":"Pid :: 468 :: ESQ :: INSERT_LOG USER :: 110876 QDATA :: 110876|||16230042103234123|||9|||20210607|||2021-06-07 15:44:11|||example@yahoo.com|||noreply@test.com|||184050|||Email dropped: User suppressed due to hard bounce|||||||||SMTP||||||||||||","time":"2021-06-07T15:44:12+05:30"}
```

**Logstash.conf**

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter
{
  if "INSERT_LOG" in [message]
  {
    grok
    {
       match => [ "message" , "%{GREEDYDATA:waste}:: ESQ :: INSERT_LOG USER :: %{NUMBER:userid1} QDATA :: %{NUMBER:userid}\|\|\|%{NUMBER:docid}\|\|\|%{NUMBER:stats}\|\|\|%{DATA:cdate}\|\|\|%{DATA:ctime}\|\|\|%{DATA:recipient_email}\|\|\|%{DATA:from_email}\|\|\|%{DATA:message_size}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:Remarks}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:cheader}\|\|\|%{DATA:subjectline}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:emailType}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:tag}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:message_id}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:scheduled_time}\|\|\|%{GREEDYDATA:acheaders} time:%{GREEDYDATA:waste2}"]
    }
    mutate
    {
      add_field  => { "USER" => "%{clientid}" }
      add_field  => { "INDEX_TYPE" => "INSERT_LOG" }
      remove_field => "waste"
      remove_field => "waste2"
    }
  }
  else
  {
    mutate
    {
      add_field  => { "INDEX_TYPE" => "OTHER" }
    }
  }
}
output
{
  if [INDEX_TYPE] == "OTHER"
  {
    redis {
      data_type => "list"
      host      => ["127.0.0.1:6379"]
      key       => "EVENTS_TEST_CUSTOM"
     }
  }
  else
  {
    redis {
      data_type => "list"
      host      => ["127.0.0.1:6379"]
      key       => "EVENTS_TEST_CUSTOM_CH"
     }
    clickhouse {
      http_hosts   => ["http://127.0.0.1:8123"]
      table        => "logs.logs_table_filebeat"
      flush_size => 1000
      pool_max => 1000
    }
  }
}
```

**Filebeat YML**

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
    paths:
      - /usr/share/filebeat/logs/EVENTS.log
    exclude_files: ['.gz$']
output.logstash:
  hosts: ['127.0.0.1:5044']
```

Comment: I assume you're using filebeat. If so, add your filebeat config to the question. You could also run `filebeat test output` and `filebeat test config`.

Comment: @tomr Have added filebeat config.

Comment: `filebeat test config` prints `Config OK` **AND** `filebeat test output` prints everything OK. @tomr

Comment: It is not clear what is not working correctly. Can you give an example of what is not working and what is the expected output?

Comment: @leandrojmp, when I append log file sequentially or manually for testing purpose, logs get formatted correctly and gets insert into redis, but when i give filepath of actual live log file (which is of same format logs i tried manually), then the output value of logstash in redis is blank with in-built values of logstash (like beat, tags, hostname, meta, version, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. If you run `tail -f /usr/share/filebeat/logs/EVENTS.log`, do you see lines being appended to that logfile by whatever is supposed to be writing there? It seems like a weird place to put logs

Comment: yes it is being appended... I am using filebeat and logstash docker and log file is mapped on  that path inside docker. @tomr

Comment: It surprises me that output `127.0.0.1:5044` is working for filebeat in docker - are you sure you've explained your setup correctly? At this point I think it's much too unclear for me to be able to help you, sorry.

Comment: in place of 127.0.0.1 it is real ip... this is just replica of my setup @tomr

Comment: the problem is that, when i append into logs file manually then it is working as expected, but when i give path of actual log file, it fails to work as expected and empty logs are giving in output

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, it turns out that when i do echo on terminal to append the log file, it gets in normal string type but the actual logs are in json type. So i need to modify my logstash.conf file to parse json. `json { source => "message"  }`